# Canvas won't stack alpha on same line

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm creating a heatmap of my gps tracks and am fighting a bit with canvas.  I'm drawing a line with 10% transparency of all my tracks and the issue is that canvas doesn't want to stack the alpha on one line, e.g. with this:

```
ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(1,1,1,0.1)';
points.forEach(point => ctx.lineTo(point.x, point.y));
ctx.stroke();
```

doesn't work as expected as everything, regardless of whether a track crosses over itself 100 times, has the color `rgba(1,1,1,0.1)`

Now I can draw each and every segment of the line separately, i.e.:

```
points.forEach(point => {
  ctx.lineTo(point.x, point.y);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(point.x, point.y);
});
```

This properly stacks the alpha values of lines drawn on top of one another, but it creates a new issue - The line caps overlap.  e.g. imagine drawing a "V".  There will be a tiny diamond shape at the top of the corner that has overlapping lines.  This is creating lots of "dots" all over my heatmap.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: For a heat map, that sounds weird to let the browser antialiasing algos and alpha rounding errors dictate how the value you show through opacity are represented in your data-viz. You would probably be better going through pixel manipulation directly and draw your lines manually: first calculate the sum of your data-values at every positions, then set the scale corresponding these sums so you can find the correct ratio for every pixel, finally draw only these final pixels on an ImageData. But this advice is mainly for normal heat-maps, you will have added complexity with these paths...

Comment: Opted towards using canvas to do this specifically because of the anitalising algorithms.  It's much easier to just say "draw a 3px wide line from A to B" than to re-implement anti-aliasing so that I don't get stupidly jagged lines

Comment: Then you can't expect any perfection. You won't be able to control this antialiasing, and yes, stacking their artifacts will give you unwanted results. IMM it's better to keep control, and moreover to know what I'm actually showing, but maybe it's not important for you your data-viz has meaning or not. You might be able to get rid of the line caps, but even then the antialiasing you like so much will not work as well when you'll stack your paths. You might actually get better results running your own.

Comment: And does it have to be transparent? If you could use only solid colors (e.g you fill your canvas background in white) you could use compositing to cleanup everything with a single draw after you made your opacity thing. This should be able to remove most unwanted artifacts while keeping the wanted ones. But it's late here so I can't give you an example.before tomorrow.

Comment: I'm remapping to solid colors based on the alpha, basically `getImageData(), remap(), putImageDat()`.  The alpha just gives me a way to actually get the heatmap.  [Here's a generated image](https://scontent-sin6-2.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/29356812_1520309634758945_1225878718199627776_o.jpg?_nc_eui2=v1%3AAeE2BxunDoM041qEkV7ea5uBaWzO-mfZUSwsQU55g_qXBm1n0ZUV0muux2wqmDBBg9JhPQaCzicYoIDj5up9AJB9K0cofNKY5WgMv71RJindZA&oh=e470310bba63f8333e3ccda7a49948b8&oe=5B3FB8C7)

Comment: And what does your data looks like exactly? Can you normalize/round your coords so that you be able to create a Map of segments, and sum up their weight without even drawing them? That would both simplify a lot the drawing, and give you the real weight of your data. Here, you don't know if "opacity:1" means "10 times" or "300 times".

Comment: The actual code is using an opacity of `0.01` which gives me sufficient distinction between from ~0-500 layers, which is more than enough for my needs.  I then find the highest alpha and re-map everything from 0-1 based on this.

Comment: It's not possible to to directly since a stroke is drawn as a single polygon with the same opacity/color. The other option will as you discovered show the overlapping segments (or gaps if mode "butt" is used etc.). The only way around this that I can think of is to manually calculate the line (segments as polygons) and joins to achieve this effect. It's more low-level but not really that hard (a little vector math is required).

Comment: A second way is to define the "line" in 3D space (using triangles/WebGL) and depth in z-space by increasing depth a tiny amount per segment, then render that using a orthographic camera with alpha and a projection that fits the map.